# What do I do about the missing `node:path` methods when bundling a project with Bun?

Tags: javascript, bun

I am trying to bundle a VS Code extension project with Bun and getting these kinds of errors when I do. I am guessing it is having trouble importing from `path`, which I am guessing is a Node specific module. What should I do about this?

```
mrakgr@Lain:/mnt/c/Users/Marko/Source/Repos/The Spiral Language/VS Code Plugin$ bun build ./src/index.ts --outdir ./out --external vscode

  ./index.js  107.19 KB


warn: Import "extname" will always be undefined because there is no matching export in "node:path"

        switch (path.extname(doc.uri.path)) {
                     ^
/mnt/c/Users/Marko/Source/Repos/The Spiral Language/VS Code Plugin/src/index.ts:159:22 8076

warn: Import "basename" will always be undefined because there is no matching export in "node:path"

                if (path.basename(doc.uri.path,".spiproj") === "package") {spiprojOpen(doc)}
                         ^
/mnt/c/Users/Marko/Source/Repos/The Spiral Language/VS Code Plugin/src/index.ts:161:26 8156

warn: Import "join" will always be undefined because there is no matching export in "node:path"

        const compiler_path = path.join(__dirname,"../compiler/Spiral.dll")
                                   ^
/mnt/c/Users/Marko/Source/Repos/The Spiral Language/VS Code Plugin/src/index.ts:261:36 13623

[180ms] bundle 27 modules
```

Comment: I just ran `bun repl` twice and tested both `let p = require('node:path');` and `import * as p from 'node:path';` followed by `p.join('a', 'b')` and got back the expected `a/b`. Might be an issue particular to WSL? I'd try it in a docker container or something to make sure it's not some weird issue with your setup.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your target is the bun runtime (or node runtime) with `bun build example.ts --outdir ./out --target <bun/node>`

Where <bun/node> is either **bun** or **node**.

The default behavior of `bun build` is to [target the browser](https://bun.sh/docs/bundler#target). The browser is a secure place where accessing the user's filesystem without explicit permission is a no-no.  Libraries such as `fs` and `path` don't work properly, therefore bun complains about including them when building for the browser. Targeting a runtime (bun/node) tells `bun build` that your code will be running locally/server-side and allow access to the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

as written on [docs](https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/nodejs-apis), bun has the compatibility with node, on section node:path the compatibility is fully implemented.
With no snippet of your code is hard to go further, by the way I would check the import `const path = require('node:path');` or I would open an issue on GitHub with the detailed steps to reproduce this case.